# display problems with my HP 8770w + Ubuntu 22.04.1 (currently has Win11 on a separate 3.5in SSD)

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, 22.04

I had to select "safe graphics" to get the GUI installer to show up. After the successful installation, the screen below is what I get when it's trying to boot. Ideas? Thanks!

Specs:

- Intel i7 3720QM (- with iGPU though I think the iGPU might be disabled. not sure how to check)
- 16GB
- Nvidia K3000M

PS: The Win11 SSD is currently not installed in the laptop. So it shouldn't interfere with the Ubuntu installation.

[image]

Comment: Until you have the correct NVIDIA driver installed it will need the safe graphics.

Comment: ... and manually sign them with MOKutil if you want to dual-boot with Windows 11. Otherwise just disable Secure Boot in UEFI.